# Do all non-antisymmetric relations have to be symmetric?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I have a bit of a problem with this. Our teacher told us to give 3 examples of binary relations which are non-antisymmetric. From all the examples I gave they were all symmetric.

From my knowledge, all asymmetric relation are also antisymmetric. So there is no example which is an asymmetric relation, and I have no idea of any other relation other than symmetric which is non-asymmetric and non-antisymmetric.

So my question is, do all non-antisymmetric relations have to be symmetric?

Edit:

**antisymmetric**: if for all $(a,b)  \in R$ $\land (b,a)  \in R \Rightarrow (a=b)$

**asymmetric**: non symmetric. if for all $(a,b)  \in R \Rightarrow (b,a)  \notin R$,

Comment: Please define "asymmetric" and "antisymmetric".

Comment: asymmetric means that if $(a, b) \in R$, then $(b,a) \notin R$.  Antisymmetric means that if ($(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R$), then $(a=b)$

Comment: antisymmetric: if for all $(a,b)  \in R$ $\land (b,a)  \in R \Rightarrow (a=b)$, asymmetric: non symmetric. if for all $(a,b)  \in R \Rightarrow (b,a)  \notin R$,

Comment: since there already are so many answers i turn my answer into a comment:since you did not specify, i assume the following:

symmetric: $a\sim b \leftrightarrow b\sim a$

antisymmetric: $a\sim b \leftrightarrow \neg b\sim a$

now for instance take the set $\Omega:=\left\{0,1\right\}$ and define:

$0\sim 1, 1\sim 1, 0\nsim 0, 1\nsim 0$.

Clearly, $\sim$ is neither symmetric, nor antisymmetric

Answer (score 4):

no, for example the relation on $\{a,b,c\}$ given by $\{(a,b),(b,c),(c,b)\}$ is not symmetric as $(a,b)$ appears and $(b,a)$ does not. It is also not antisymmetric as we have $(b,c)$ and $(c,b)$.

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: does the same happen for poor ones?

Answer (score 2):

Go back to the definition.  A symmetric relation has $xRy \Leftrightarrow yRx$ for all $x,y$.  An antisymmetric relation has $(xRy \wedge yRx) \implies x=y$.  Take the relation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ consisting of $\{(1,2),(3,4),(4,3)\}$.  Having $(1,2)$ and not $(2,1)$ makes it not symmetric.  The other two pairs make it not antisymmetric.